# Dhtmlx - Create multiple tasks in one row

Tags: dhtmlx, gantt-chart

can I create a gantt chart by Dhtmlx with multiple tasks in one row?
some gantt charts like "angular-gantt" and "Anychart" supported this but I can't find any way to do it with Dhtmlx gantt

I want to create a gantt chart like this image:

[image: Gantt image]

** Angular-gantt and any chart are very very slow for huge data

Comment: Currently there is no easy way to create multiple tasks in one row.

Comment: You just can either  [display subtasks in one row when Project task is closed](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/04_customization/18_subtasks_displaying.html) or [split task](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/04_customization/11_split_task.html). Check samples how to implement it.

Comment: thank you @Polina, can you suggest any gantt chart to handle large amount of data and also support task period?

Comment: DHTMLX Gantt Chart is suit for these requirements. It's realy awesome and easy-customizable component,  it can handle large amount of data - read info about smart rendering. Task period is supported too.
You can check Gannt possibilities in the samples on official site.

Comment: @Polina Hi Polina, has this feature (multiple tasks in one row) been implemented? Thank you

Comment: @User9023 Yes, it is "Split tasks" functionality. Please find details and the sample that demonstrates how it works in the documentation here https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__split_tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it became possible since dhtmlx Gantt version 6.2. The functionality called "Split Tasks". Find details on how to implement it in the [guide](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__split_tasks.html).
Also, check the [sample](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/04_customization/11_split_task.html) that demonstrates how it works.

Comment: it seems to be available only with a paid membership? Also splitting tasks is not the same as having multiple tasks. It makes easy things vey complicated and as soon as you want to import different excel sheets with different amounts of columns, you would need to readjust everything. Why dont you bring in the functionality of scheduler that already has this covered? Thank you

Comment: Yes, PRO edition is paid. Splitting tasks is the same as having multiple tasks because in data you have a record for each "split task". Scheduler and Gantt are separate DHTMLX components and we are not seeking to make them the same.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I found a free alternative that supports multiple tasks per row